# Go back to initial root ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

In my app, I have a Login Controller which is my initial viewController, and when I log into the app, I change my Root ViewController thanks to this code :

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let newVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
self.view.window?.rootViewController = newVC
```

But now, I would like to go back to my Login Page when I click on Disconnect button. The problem is that I don't manage to go to this page. Whatever I try, it reloads the SecondViewController but not the LoginController. Here is what I have tried :

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let projectVC = newVC.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginController") as! LoginController
self.view.window?.rootViewController = newVC
```

Or

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let newVC = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController()
self.view.window?.rootViewController = newVC
```

Is it possible to go back to the initial viewcontroller ? Or is there a way to just reload my app ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: you shouldnt really change the root VC again, just present the 'Main' from the login?

Comment: Seems there're mistypes in code, no? In second block of code you instantiate view controller from newVC, and mention projectVC which isn't used.

Comment: Yes indeed it's an error when I have rewritten the code. So finally I will not change the root VC after login. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to not change rootViewController property on a window is to make some parent view controller as "root" and add/change child view controllers (Login, Main, etc.) to it as needed.

Comment: Ok, so I will modify my app. Thanks !